# Prevent screen standby for always on xubuntu 20.04 via SSH

Tags: xubuntu, kiosk, standby

I have access to a terminal with SSH, to a XUBUNTU 20.04 that working like a kiosk.

How can I set this machine in an "always on mode" through SSH?

I need this machine been always on and the screen always viewable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sets some of the options:

```
nano .xinitrc
    #!/bin/sh
    xset -dpms
    xset s off
    xset s noblank
```

From : https://linux.die.net/man/1/xset

The -dpms option disables DPMS (Energy Star) features.
The s option lets you set the screen saver parameters. This option accepts up to two numerical parameters, a 'blank/noblank' flag, an 'expose/noexpose' flag, an 'on/off' flag, an 'activate/reset' flag, or the 'default' flag.

For full usage of the command please visit the link above.

This will disable power options and screensaver for your display. As much as I'm aware Ubuntu doesn't suspend/sleep/hibernate whole PC automatically for always-powered devices, at least I never had Ubuntu do this on me without setting it up on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I've added

```
xset -dpms
xset s off
xset s noblank
```

to

> /usr/share/xsessions/chromeKiosk.sh

and it fixed the issue